# What workarounds/coping-strategies have you implemented to deal with multiple tabs v. two connection limit issues?

Tags: ajax, tabs, two-connection-limit

The two connection limit can be particularly troublesome when you have multiple tabs open simultaneously.  Besides "ignore the problem," what coping mechanisms have you seen used to get multiple tabs both doing heavily interactive Ajax despite the two connection limit?

Comment: Note: both IE8 and Firefox 3 have increased the limit to 6

Comment: Have you found out a solution yet?... I wonder if nudging the question up would be acceptable here...

Answer (score 3):

If you send your Ajax requests to a different subdomain they won't interfere with the connection limit of your regular pages. It will cost an extra DNS lookup though

Answer (score 1):

The two connection limit is a "suggestion" and this [article](http://www.oreillynet.com/xml/blog/2006/10/what_i_didnt_know_about_xhr.html) describes how to get around it where possible.  Other Firefox configuration is discussed on this about the [about:config](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_FAQs_:_About:config_Entries) capability in Firefox.

Also, if you own the website, you can tweak the performance of the site using suggestions form this [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529309) from the Chief Performance Yahoo.

Comment: The limit is more than a suggestion, the HTTP 1.1 specification lists it as a SHOULD, which in RFC-speak is a lot stronger than a "suggestion".